# jQuery if div empty

Tags: jquery, whitespace, is-empty

I'm working on wordpress template where div.post-thumb is empty but have dynamic white spaces.

```
<div class="post-thumb">    </div>
<div class="post-text"></div>
```

I'm using following script to detect if div.post-thumb is empty.

```
$('.post-thumb').each(function(){
if ($(this).html()=='') $('.post-text').css('marginLeft','50px');
});
```

Problem with this script is "Dynamic white spaces within div.post-thumb"

How to get rid of this issue? Is there any other way to detect if div is empty excluding white spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `trim` function to remove whitespace:

```
$('.post-thumb').each(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).html()) == '') $('.post-text').css('marginLeft','50px');
});
```

`trim` removes all spaces, new lines and tabs from the beginning or end of a string. See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) for more information.